# Algorithm ByteRun, decompression gone wrong, .bmp

Tags: c++, bmp, compression

I have a little problem with algorithm ByteRun(very similar to RLE). Well when i make the decompression smth go wrong and my output isn't the same as input. The orginal cookie is saved in format .bmp (24 pixels). The output should be our format eg. ".xd".

I saw (as far) only 4 options and it depends on how many pixels we have in  width.

for 421  we have

[image]

for 422 we have

[image]

for 423 we have

[image]

and for 424 we have

[image]

and the original:

[image]

Tbh I thought that I consider padding but idk what makes my poor cookie broke. :( Please help me save the cookie. :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct colour                               // structure of every pixel BGR
{
    unsigned char   b;
    unsigned char   g;
    unsigned char   r;
};

unsigned int reading_and_writing_the_header(FILE *file_in, FILE *file_out, unsigned char header[])
{

unsigned int width = 0;
unsigned int height = 0;
unsigned int bite_for_pixel = 0;
unsigned int amount_of_pixels = 0;
unsigned int padding = 0;
unsigned int row = 0;

fread(header, 1, 54, file_in);                      // reading the header  // 1=sizeof(unsigned int) = sizof(uni8_t)
fwrite(header, 1, 54, file_out);                    // wrting header


width = *(unsigned int*)&header[18];
height = *(unsigned int*)&header[22];
bite_for_pixel = *(unsigned int*)&header[28];

padding = width % 4;                                    // counting padding
row = width * 3 + padding;                              // bites in a row
amount_of_pixels = height * row;                        // amount of bites after header
return amount_of_pixels;
}

void compression_ByteRun(FILE *file_in,FILE *file_out, unsigned int aop)
{
colour *q = new colour[aop];

fread(q, 1, aop, file_in);
int k = 0;
colour x, y;
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
char *the_same_colours = new char[4];
char *diffrent_colours = new char[128 * 3 + 1];

while (k < (aop / 3))
{
    x = q[k];
    y = q[k + 1];
    if (x.r == y.r && x.b == y.b && x.g == y.g)         //if the same R and B and G                                                     
    {
        if (counter1 == 126)                          // not sure about what exactly should be here 
        {
            the_same_colours[0] = (counter1)*(-1);
            fwrite(the_same_colours, 1, 4, file_out);
            counter1 = 0;
        }
        if (counter2 != 0)
        {
            diffrent_colours[0] = counter2 / 3 - 1;
            fwrite(diffrent_colours, 1, counter2 + 1, file_out);
            counter2 = 0;
        }

        counter1++;
        k++;
        continue;
    }
    else                                        // if we have diffrent colours side by side
    {
        if (counter1 != 0)
        {
            the_same_colours[0] = (counter1)*(-1);
            the_same_colours[1] = x.b;
            the_same_colours[2] = x.g;
            the_same_colours[3] = x.r;
            fwrite(the_same_colours, 1, 4, file_out);
            counter1 = 0;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            diffrent_colours[counter2 + 1] = x.b;
            diffrent_colours[counter2 + 2] = x.g;
            diffrent_colours[counter2 + 3] = x.r;
            counter2 = counter2+ 3;


            if (counter2 / 3 == 127)                    // same here, not sure about what exactly should be here 
            {
                diffrent_colours[0] = counter2 / 3 - 1;
                fwrite(diffrent_colours, 1, counter2 + 1, file_out);
                counter2 = 0;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
}
}

void decompression_ByteRun(FILE *file_in,FILE *file_out)
{
char x;                                 // variavle where we keep how many colours we need 2 write 
char y, z, o;                           // variables for comparing values
bool  game_over;                        // variable for checking if the file isn't over 


game_over = fread(&x, 1, 1, file_in);                                                   
while (game_over == true)
{
    if (x >= 0)                         // if we had diffrent colours side by dide
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= x * 3 + 3; i++)
        {
            fread(&y, 1, 1, file_in);
            fwrite(&y, 1, 1, file_out);
        }
        game_over = fread(&x, 1, 1, file_in);
        continue;
    }

    else                                // if we have the same colours
    {
        fread(&z, 1, 1, file_in);
        fread(&o, 1, 1, file_in);
        fread(&y, 1, 1, file_in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= (-(x)+1); i++)
        {
            fwrite(&z, 1, 1, file_out);
            fwrite(&o, 1, 1, file_out);
            fwrite(&y, 1, 1, file_out);
        }
        game_over = fread(&x, 1, 1, file_in);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
FILE *file_in;
FILE *file_out;
int number = 0;
char* name = new char;
char* name_out = new char;
unsigned char header[54];
unsigned int amount_of_pixels = 0;

cout << "Write input file: " << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << endl;

cout << "Write output file:" << endl;
cin >> name_out;
cout << endl;

cout << "What u wanna do (1- compression or 2- decompression ";
cin >> number;

file_in = fopen(name, "rb");
if (file_in == NULL)
{
    cout << "Error we couldn't open that file.\n Contact our IT group 4 more help" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}

file_out = fopen(name_out, "wb");
if (file_out == NULL)
{
    cout << "Error we couldn't open that file.\n Contact our IT group 4 more help" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}

switch (number)
{
case 1:
    cout << "Compression Byterun" << endl;
    amount_of_pixels = reading_and_writing_the_header(file_in, file_out, header);
    compression_ByteRun(file_in, file_out, amount_of_pixels);
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Decompression Byterun" << endl;
    amount_of_pixels = reading_and_writing_the_header(file_in, file_out, header);
    decompression_ByteRun(file_in, file_out);
    break;
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to break down your problem into something more restricted.  _i.e._ find a short sequence that does not get restored after compression and decompression, then try to debug.  It's not much use posting images and a large program, expecting us to debug it for you.  Once you have found your sequence, if you are unable to determine the issue with your algorithm, then post the input and expected result, and _only_ the relevant code.

Comment: I made the image links actually images (AFAIK new users aren't allowed to post images). That does make the post a bit tall, but oh well.

Comment: You have 0-3 bytes of padding at the end of every row, but your compressor is treating that padding as image data.

Comment: @paddy tbh I'm new with programming and I don't how to do it. And I thought that this is the relevant part of my code ( My program has 800+ lines).

Comment: @immibis Thank you very much. Maybe it's taller but I think that now it's better. Thank you.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you for your help, because it's probably my whole problem. But oh well what should I do now? I should read one row of pixels, write it to the file_out, read padding and move on to the next row and so on?

Comment: One way is to read the row and padding, process that row until you get to the padding, then read the next one (ignoring the padding bytes).